# React Native Windows UWP - Is it possible to use modal component?

Tags: react-native, uwp

I tried to use modal component for UWP Apps using [React Native Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/tree/master/docs) but I got a Warning like below.

> Warning: Native component for "RTCModalHostView" does not exist.

What can I do to use modal component for UWP Apps with [React Native Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/tree/master/docs)?

Comment: is that a custom component? seems like you forgot to import the component from your project or library

Comment: no, it is not a custom component. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html

Comment: I imported the component like this: `import { Modal, Text, TouchableHighlight, View } from 'react-native';`

Comment: Do you have any ideas to use modal component for UWP Apps with React Native Windows...?

Comment: that component is not available yet on UWP, you can check available component here : https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/blob/master/docs/CoreParityStatus.md

Comment: the temporary solution to this modal for now you need to create a custom component: this post has an example how to do it : https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/618

Answer (score 2):

The official modal component is not available for now,
you can check available components from :

https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/blob/master/docs/CoreParityStatus.md

The temporary solution to create modal is by using a custom component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import Styles from './Styles/ModalStyles'

export default class Modal extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    visible: React.PropTypes.bool,
    children: React.PropTypes.object
  }

  render () {
    if (!this.props.visible) return (<View />)

    return (
      <View style={Styles.modal}>
        {this.props.children}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

style example:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

export default StyleSheet.create({
  modal: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
})
```

here is the complete reference : https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/618